# Zipfile fails to unzip files present in an NFS drive

Tags: python-3.x, celery, zip, nfs

**Existing Workflow**:

Celery Task periodically pulls a zip file from S3 bucket to /tmp/ and zipfile extracts that to a new folder for processing.

**Challenge**: The zip file being variable in size, made me to add a lot of block storage and somethings let to Out of Disk Errors.

**New Workflow**:

I mounted an AWS EFS drive to my /efs/ path.

Celery Task periodically pulls a zip file from S3 bucket to /efs/ and zipfile extracts that to a new folder for processing. However the zipfile fails to extract the file present on /efs/ drive with the following trace:

```
[2019-11-22 23:32:51,697: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] Downloaded file
[2019-11-22 23:32:51,697: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] Stored the file at
[2019-11-22 23:32:51,697: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] /efs/fcb3b551-dcc5-48fb-a8ca-7cf6fd2f9cfd.zip
[2019-11-22 23:32:54,410: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task analyzer.tasks.convert_csv[834df7ff-4dcf-4f04-b3b5-9956da867cf4] raised unexpected: error('Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid code lengths set',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/kirke/kirke_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 375, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/kirke/kirke_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 632, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/kirke/backend/analyzer/tasks.py", line 179, in convert_csv
    zip_ref.extractall(temp_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1524, in extractall
    self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1579, in _extract_member
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 872, in read
    data = self._read1(n)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 948, in _read1
    data = self._decompressor.decompress(data, n)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid code lengths set
```

And the strange fact is that when I run a normal python shell and try to extract the zip file present on the /efs/ it works !!

**My Environment**

```
aiodns==2.0.0
aiohttp==3.6.2
amqp==2.5.2
async==0.6.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
Babel==2.7.0
billiard==3.5.0.5
boto3==1.10.25
botocore==1.12.197
celery==4.1.1
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.2.3
django-enumfields==1.0.0
django-extensions==2.2.1
djangorestframework==3.10.1
docutils==0.14
flower==0.9.3
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
idna-ssl==1.1.0
importlib-metadata==0.23
jmespath==0.9.4
kombu==4.6.6
more-itertools==7.2.0
multidict==4.6.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
pycares==3.0.0
pycparser==2.19
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
redis==3.3.11
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
six==1.13.0
slackclient==2.0.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
tornado==5.1.1
typing==3.7.4
typing-extensions==3.7.4
urllib3==1.25.7
vine==1.3.0
websocket-client==0.56.0
yarl==1.3.0
zipp==0.6.0
```

Any ideas ? Suggestions ?

Comment: Did you try to test that ZIP file with `zip -T downloaded-file.zip` to find out whether it is OK?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. zipfile is OK

Comment: Is file larger than 4GB?

Comment: no it is of 1.5 GB

Comment: Is it password protected ZIP file? I think I saw similar error when using wrong password...

Comment: No, as I mentioned in my question, when I am running the same command to unzip from python shell it works.

Comment: Did you try to run it on the same machine where the task that raised the exception is running?

Comment: Yes, same machine. everything is same.